# jQuery child selector help

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, children

There must be a better way to select this element.  Can someone please help me out.  I've tried nth-child and last-child, but I'm not getting it.

Here's my code:

```
<li>
    <div class="pic" style="width:300px; text-align:center;">
        <img src='path/to/my/image.jpg' />
    </div>
    <p>
        <span title="<?php echo $media_title; ?>">Title: <?php echo stringDisplay($media_title,12); ?></span><br />
        <span title="<?php echo $media_filename; ?>">File: <?php echo stringDisplay($media_filename,18); ?></span><br />
        Updated: <?php echo date("n/j/y", $lastUpdated).' at '.date("h:ia",$lastUpdated); ?>
    </p>
    <a class="link" href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($(this).parent().children('.pic').children().children().children().attr('src'));" style="margin-bottom:3px;">Preview</a>
</li>
```

I'm trying to select the image source of the image in the first div from the link below it. The best I could come up with is:

```
alert($(this).parent().children('.pic').children().children().children().attr('src'));
```

Comment: Okay, I updated the formatting so that it's readable now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(this).parent().find('div.pic>img').attr('src');
```

N.B. I would strongly recommend **not** using `onclick` to bind your Javascript event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Find the first sibling with an image element and return the src attribute.

```
$(this).prevAll().find('img:first').attr('src');
```

Comment: wow!  that was fast!  thank you geniuses - I just can't seem to wrap my head around jquery selectors.  thanx!

Comment: You are welcome.  Feel free to post more questions.  It is recommended that you click the green arrow next to the answer that helped you once you have verified it - that will keep the StackOverflow crowd helping you out as some get grumpy if you do not accept answers (not me though)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(this).siblings('.pic').children('img').attr('src');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
- http://api.jquery.com/children/
- http://api.jquery.com/attr/

There are many ways to traverse in jQuery:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/